# relational database with php

Tags: php, mysql

well,
I've got 3 tables with foreign keys on similar words:

**assignment**:
idassignment,
*idshift*
*idworker*

**shift**:
*idshift*
name

**worker**:
*idworker*
name

I made a select (using joins where needed) that takes all of the relevant data from them.
I want to make an array that resembles the DB's structure.

today I just iterate over assignments, and use keys from that table
 to look into shift and worker.

any comment would help.

example:
(ignore fields not specified in the end example)
I use this SQL:

```
SELECT
    `assignment`.`assignmentid`,
    `assignment`.`date`,
    `assignment`.`shiftid`,
    `assignment`.`workerid`,
    `shift`.`ShiftsID`,
    `shift`.`WorkersNum`,
    `shift`.`ShiftsType`,
    `shift`.`length`,
    `worker`.`WorkerID`,
    `worker`.`FirstName`,
    `worker`.`LastName`,
    `worker`.`Email`,
    `worker`.`phone`
    FROM `mydb`.`assignment` LEFT JOIN `mydb`.`shift` ON ShiftsID=shiftid
    LEFT JOIN `mydb`.`worker` USING (`workerid`)
```

with this data:

```
assigment
(1,1,1),
(2,2,1),
(3,2,2)

shift
(1,"morning")
(2,"lunch")

worker
(1,"john")
(2,"doe")
```

and I want the array to look like:

```
Array
{
    [0]=>Array
        {
            [assignmentID]==>1;
            [shift]==>Array
                {
                    [shiftid]=1;
                    [name]="morning";
                }
            [worker]==>Array
                {
                    [idworker]=1;
                    [name]="john";
                }
        }
    [1]=>Array
        {
            [assignmentID]==>2;
            [shift]==>Array
                {
                    [shiftid]=2;
                    [name]="lunch";
                }
            [worker]==>Array
                {
                    [idworker]=1;
                    [name]="john";
                }
        }
    [2]=>Array
        {
            [assignmentID]==>3;
            [shift]==>Array
                {
                    [shiftid]=2;
                    [name]="lunch";
                }
            [worker]==>Array
                {
                    [idworker]=2;
                    [name]="doe";
                }
        }
}
```

I just used a function for each table which returns me the array for it.

```
function shift(id)
function worker(id)
```

and I traverse assignment between dates.
and call those and put them all into an array;

Comment: Please provide an example of what you want.

Comment: I'm not a big fan or ORMs. But maybe an ORM like Doctrine (http://www.doctrine-project.org/) could help you if you're not familiar with DBs.

Comment: please provide what you currently have made - it makes helping easier

Comment: @t00ny,  I'm very familiar with DBs, and an ORM is an good to use if I started the site with, now it's late for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = /* your sql statement */;
if (($data = mysql_query($sql)) !== false)
{
  $details = array();
  while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) !== false)
  {
    $details[] = array(
      'assignmentID' => $row['assignmentid'],
      'shift' => array(
        'shiftid' => $row['ShiftsID'],
        'name' => // i don't see `shift`.`name`, but that goes here
      ),
      'worker' => array(
        'idworker' => $row['WorkerID'],
        'name' => $row['FirstName']
      )
    );
  }

  // $details is now populated with the structure you were looking for.
}
```

Something like that? Though your initial database column names and those in your query don't align, so I'm a little confused. Made a best-guess for that.

**EDIT**

Could also get more creative and check if worker/shift are supplied (given a left join) and then only add the array information for them when results are returned in the query. e.g.

```
$details[] = array(
  'assignmentID' => $row['assignmentid']
  'shift' => (!is_null($row['ShiftsID'])?array(
    ...
  ):null), // null when there's no shift
  'worker' => (!is_null($row['WorkerID'])?array(
    ...
  ):null) // null when there's no worker
);
```

Comment: yeah i've commented that i'm looking for the general idea here, thanks, is there a way for doing something like this without explicitly stating column names?

Comment: @shevski: As others have stated, you'd have to build the database structure in to an object structure for PHP, then have code that relates them back and forth between PHP/DB. A lot of work to implement however. I tend to re-create classes in PHP that mimic my DB structure, then pass queries off to those objects when they're being referenced. (like LINQ would do if you're familiar with .NET)